# Getting a soft 404 error on redirect to login page in Yii

Tags: php, yii

I'm using Yii 1.1.17, and i noticed on some of my pages where i want just registered users to be able to view I'm getting a soft 404 error on Google's webmasters tools.

For example

`http://www.example.com/sell/` when you go to `http://www.example.com/sell/view` it would redirect you to `http://www.example.com/login`

Right now i only have 240 soft 404 errors. The view action was not set to registered users only at first.But after a couple of months after launching my site. I changed it. Then the errors starting poping up.

Is there a way to fix this? or a work around?

here is accessRules for the `view` action that is only for registered users:

```
public function accessRules()
    {
        return array(
            array('allow',  
                'actions'=>array('index', 'new'),
                'users'=>array('*'),
            ),
            array('allow',
                'actions'=>array('view'),
                'users'=>array('@'),
            ),
            array('allow',
                'actions'=>array('admin','delete', 'update', 'create','update','upload'),
                'expression'=>'app()->user->isAdmin()',
            ),
            array('deny', 
                'users'=>array('*'),
            ),
        );
    }
```

Comment: show the  the code of the related controller please..

Comment: @scaisEdge updated question

Comment: Pls show the `urlManager` rules from your `config.php`

Comment: Which page is giving you error? `http://www.example.com/sell/` or `http://www.example.com/sell/view` or both?

Comment: @TaReQMahMooD the view

Comment: @user2636556 have you tried [Fetch as Google](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6066468?rd=2) to see what your `view` page looks like to Google's crawler?

Comment: @topher yeah. on a page where only loged in users are allowed to access, i redirect to a login page. and google webmaster keeps giving me a soft 404 error.

Comment: @user2636556 Does loading your login page directly on Fetch as Google also result in a soft 404?

Comment: @topher no. just the pages that are only for registered users. for example `http://www.example.com/sell/view/?id=1`  will redirect to `http://www.example.com/login` and i get the 404 error. (404 for ALL ?id=<ID>)  but `http://www.example.com/login` i get no such errors

Answer (score 1):

You could add a `deniedCallback` as

```
public function accessRules()
    {
        return array(
            array('allow',  
                'actions'=>array('index', 'new'),
                'users'=>array('*'),
                'deniedCallback' => array($this, 'redirectToLogin'), 
            ),
            array('allow',
                'actions'=>array('view'),
                'users'=>array('@'),
                'deniedCallback' => array($this, 'redirectToLogin'), 
            ),
            array('allow',
                'actions'=>array('admin','delete', 'update', 'create','update','upload'),
                'expression'=>'app()->user->isAdmin()',
                'deniedCallback' => array($this, 'redirectToLogin'), 
            ),
            array('deny', 
                'users'=>array('*'),
                'deniedCallback' => array($this, 'redirectToLogin'), 
            ),
        );
    }

    public function redirectToLogin($user = null, $rule = null){
        Yii::app()->controller->redirect('/login', true, 403);
    }
```

You can then redirect with whatever status code you'd like.

You can find out more about `deniedCallback` [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CAccessControlFilter).

Find out more about `redirect` [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CController#redirect-detail)

Comment: getting this error now `Missing argument 2 for DealershipController::redirectToLogin()`

Comment: updated answer to have default values null as `function redirectToLogin($user = null, $rule = null){`

Comment: update `/login` in `redirecToLogin` with your `login_controller/action` for your Yii app, to redirect to a particular controller/action.

Comment: changed it to `usr/default/login` .. same results

Comment: changed it to this. `$this->redirect('/login/');` and now it redirects. but lets see if i still get the soft 404 error before i approve your answer :)

Comment: FYI when i add this `$this->redirect('/login/', true, 403);` the page dies. only this works for me `$this->redirect('/login/');` any ideas?

Comment: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CController#redirect-detail mentions `$terminate` defaults to true anyway, and default status code is 302 (redirect), however the idea here was to show 403 access denied, or even a 401 unauthorised.

Comment: still not working for me. all i get is a white blank page

Answer (score 0):

In a simple way, you just need to identify it to the controller. If not a user login, it will automatically be taken to the login page. Like the example below:

```
public function actionView($id)
{
    if(!Yii::app()->user->isGuest)
    {   
        $this->redirect(array('/site/login'));
    }
    else
    {
        $this->render('view',array(
        'model'=>$this->loadModel($id),
        ));
    }
}
```

Hopefully can help

Answer (score 0):

you just embed dbmanager / rbac library to your yii apps,

```
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-rbac-dbmanager.html
```