# yii redirect with 403

Tags: php, yii, google-search-console

I'm using Yii 1.1.17, and in me action i have

`$this->redirect(url('sell/default/index'), true, 403);`

all i get is a blank white page. with no errors even in log. But this works

`$this->redirect(url('sell/default/index'));`

problem is i want to set a 403 error, so i don't get a soft 404 error on Google.

I also tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34922203/getting-a-soft-404-error-on-redirect-to-login-page-in-yii), but i'm still getting the same results.

Any ideas?

Comment: Setting `$terminate` to TRUE terminates the application, set to FALSE. [Redirect()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHttpRequest#redirect-detail).

Comment: @InsaneSkull same results

Comment: why you were using `url()`?

Comment: @InsaneSkull short code for `createURL()`

Comment: you don't have to create url, if you are in current context.

Comment: @InsaneSkull `$this->redirect('/sell/default/index', false, 403);` same results

Comment: working for me,  `$this->redirect('/sell/default/index', 403);`

Comment: @InsaneSkull yii version?

Comment: @InsaneSkull where is false/true?

Comment: not required. it's optional. Tested on yii2.

Comment: @InsaneSkull i'm using Yii 1.1.17

Comment: It also work on Yii1.

Answer (score 0):

What if you throw an Exception...!

```
  throw new CHttpException(403,'Your Error message');
```

Comment: that will show a 403 error message page. i want to redirect unregistered users to `/sell/default/index` and avoid having a soft 404 warning on google webmaster

Answer (score 0):

```
  throw new HttpException(403, Yii::t('app', 'You are not allowed to perform this action.'));
```